# Drawing an image from a cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Is the any drawing / export tool that I can use to turn a `cloudformation` **template** into a diagram.

In need to export my `cloudformation` **stack** into an *image*, or a *graphviz* file.

Regards,

Answer (score 6):

You can use the latest version of the [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/releases/tag/v0.29.4) tool to get a graph of resources from your template.

Use it like this:

```
pip3 install cfn-lint pydot
cfn-lint template.json -g
```

For example, it will generate a DOT file that renders like this:

[image: Resource dependency graph]

Which corresponds to this template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Sample template that demonstrates Fn::GetAtt",
  "Resources": {
    "DetectTextInImage": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "DetectTextInImageRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "DetectTextInImageBucketEvent1Permission": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "Properties": {}
    },
    "DetectTextInImageRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {}
    },
    "ResultsTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {}
    },
    "SourceImageBucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "NotificationConfiguration": {
          "LambdaConfigurations": [
            {
              "Function": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "DetectTextInImage",
                  "Arn"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The [CloudFormation Linter Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) also has a [resource dependency graph preview button](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code/pull/106) in the top right while editing CloudFormation templates:

[image: Resource dependency graph in Visual Studio Code extension]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [AWS CloudFormation designer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/designer). Click on **Open**, then upload your template. Finally take a screenshot of the result to have it in an image format.

Here's an exemple of what the result might look like:

[image]

For more information, have a look at the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/working-with-templates-cfn-designer-overview.html).

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Just a note, make sure you are viewing the "Template" tab at the bottom and select YAML or JSON before pasting in your code.