# Using CloudFormation Designer to auto generate CF template visualizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to automatically generate visualizations from CloudFormation templates. 
 I was wondering if this was possible to do with CloudFormation designer? Perhaps an API exist that I can use to import a CloudFormation Template and generate a visualization.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/working-with-templates-cfn-designer-overview.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing an image from a cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102947/drawing-an-image-from-a-cloudformation-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at today, there is no API to create these diagrams. I have asked for this before to AWS and there is still "no ETA on this".